# Getting apache to respond to http broadcasts

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, http

I was wondering if there is a way to configure Apache to respond to http requests sent to the broadcast address (ie. 192.168.1.255). Thanks

Comment: The broadcast address is in 192.168.1.255 in /24 networks... And what is the objective of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP and HTTPS protocols operate over TCP/IP which does not support broadcast addressing like, for instance, UDP/IP does so there is no valid concept of a broadcast HTTP request.

IIRC Apache can be made to do multicast responses to multiple clients but I don't think that is what you are looking for, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast.

If multicast is what you are looking for then you should update your question. In any case, adding to your question what you are trying to achieve might help get you answers with suggestions for what might work.